# Visualise javascript load chain

Tags: javascript, chain

When I look at our website I see that a lot of external javascript files are loaded through the bannering network we use. One javascript file loads another, which loads another, and so on.

Is there a way to visualise this "javascript load chain"?

Comment: I would look through browser plugins. Otherwise it sounds pretty hard, cause "loading" a script is simply DOM manipulation. Also I very rarely see this done, so I am surprised that you have a "chain" to analyze.

Answer (score 0):

some javascript library has your want, like require.js,Backbone.js, you can search to learn more, I just know them but has don't used...